# Login window language has changed after update on Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, login, updates, language, locale

After the latest update (beginning of Dec. 2012) on Snow Leopard my login window language has changed. My system is set to be in english but the login windows now is in french.

Currently I am in France so I suspect that during the update something has revealed my location and installed something in the locale of the current location.

It doesn't seem fair to me, I want to switch it back to english but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `sudo languagesetup` and change the language from the menu. It modifies the AppleLanguages array in `/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences -> Language&Text, and replace those parameters that were changed from french to english. Also you might be need to download language pack for your language